# How GAE detect the right handler for a task queue?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to work with Queues in Google App Engine but I don't understand a point, after reading the doc again and again :

If I define a queue in queue.yaml like this :

```
queue:
 - name: invoice
   rate: 2/m
```

And an handler in app.yaml like this :

```
handlers:
- url: /tasks/invoice
  script: invoice.py
  login: admin
```

And I add the tasks like this (Python) :

```
taskqueue.add(queue_name='invoice', name='invoice-{0}'.format(str(datetime.datetime.now()),), params={'id': id})
```

How does Google map the 'invoice' queue to my script ?!

I saw on an example online that the handler url is the following (adapted) :

```
url: /_ah/queue/invoice
```

Does adding `/_ah/queue/` will help GAE map the queue_`name` with the right handler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push tasks reference their implementation via URL. If you do not specify a worker URL, the task uses a default worker URL named after the queue:

```
/_ah/queue/[queue_name]
```

A queue's default URL is used if, and only if, a task does not have a worker URL of its own. If a task does have its own worker URL, then it is only invoked at the worker URL.

```
# Add the task to the 'queue1' queue and use explicit handler (/path/to/your/handler/)
taskqueue.add(queue_name='queue1', url='/path/to/your/handler/', params={'key': value})

# Add the task to the 'queue1' queue and use the default handler (/_ah/queue/queue1)
taskqueue.add(queue_name='queue1', params={'key': value})
```

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_URL_endpoints).

Answer (score 0):

The `queue.yaml` file is an **application-level** configuration (together with `dispatch.yaml`, `cron.yaml`, `index.yaml` and `dos.yaml`).

The queue definitions from the `queue.yaml` file are available to **any** file in your app code, they are not (and they don't need to be) mapped to a specific file. Think globals.